# Export Variable in Linux Terminal with Multiple Strings Terraform

Tags: shell, variables, terminal, syntax, terraform

I have this variable in Terraform called "example". The variable is a type of "list(strings)" and I need to export that variable in my terminal, when running Terraform plan (i cannot put the value in code, so I have to export it):

```
export VAR_example=""xyz", "abc", "123""
```

but when I run this^, it gives me error:

```
│ Error: Invalid number literal
│ 
│   on <value for var.example> line 1:
│   (source code not available)
│ 
│ Failed to recognize the value of this number literal.
╵
╷
│ Error: Extra characters after expression
│ 
│   on <value for var.example> line 1:
│   (source code not available)
│ 
│ An expression was successfully parsed, but extra characters were found after it.
```

Then, I tried exporting it like this:

```
export VAR_example='"xyz", "abc", "123"'
```

Then, I got the error:

```
╷
│ Error: Extra characters after expression
│ 
│   on <value for var.example> line 1:
│   (source code not available)
│ 
│ An expression was successfully parsed, but extra characters were found after it.
```

Now, I am not sure how to export it at all. Any solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a list of strings, you could provide it this way as well [1]:

```
terraform apply -var='examples=["xyz", "abc", "123"]'
```

However, since an environment variable needs to be used you could set it like:

```
export TF_VAR_examples='["xyz", "abc", "123"]'
```

Note that you need to prefix any environment variables with `TF_` in order for Terraform to pick them up [2].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#variables-on-the-command-line

[2] https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/environment-variables#tf_var_name

Comment: Hi! Ty for the help... I know about [2] I just forgot to add it in my question. Also, for [1], I tried it but it did not work. Gives me error:
```│ Error: No value for required variable
│ 
│   on variables.tf line 129:
│  129: variable "examples" {
│ 
│ The root module input variable "example" is not set, and has no default value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a value for this variable.``` @Marko E

Comment: Well, you didn't add the variable definition, so I was using what you added to the question, which was singular, i.e. `example`. I have set it to `examples` now in my answer.